# Hook into sendmail

Tags: sendmail, smtp

I have an app on a server that sends mail via the local system's 'sendmail'.  I want to write a program that takes the payload of the message, modifies it, and then sends it on to the original recipients.

I am running sendmail 8.14.4-8 on a Red Hat 6.4 server.

I thought that I could replace the link to /usr/sbin/sendmail with a link to my own script that would do the work and then delegate to the actual sendmail binary.

That didn't seem to work, so next I tried setting up a programmable SMTP server on the same host and tried to get sendmail to relay the messages to it, but sendmail didn't want to relay to any port other than 25.  I tried using the following lines:

```
dnl define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 8025')dnl
dnl define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 8025')dnl
```

My reading suggested that would work, but sendmail just kept trying port 25.

Anyone have any other ideas how I could approach this problem?

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: Your first solution -- replacing the system `sendmail` with a wrapper script -- should have worked just fine.  What do you mean by "that didn't seem to work"?

Comment: Have you thought about implementing a milter to do this?

Comment: @larsks - When I tested by echoing to the local `mail` program, I could see the shell script create a temp file, so I knew it worked.  When I tried to have the real app send mail, I didn't see a temp file, but I saw the message get processed in /var/log/maillog.

Comment: @Mike B - I am no sendmail expert-- I don't know anything about implementing a filter, but if you pointed me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: It sounds as if your application isn't actually calling the `sendmail` binary.  Possibly you have an smtp server listening on `localhost` and the program is talking to that directly.  If that's the case, @MikeB's suggestion of using a [milter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milter) is a reasonable idea, as is implementing some sort of filtering SMTP proxy server.  There are lots of guides out there to both.

Comment: @larsks - I added some more debugging statements to my script to see what was going on.  It looks like my script *is* getting called, just not how I expected.  I thought sendmail just read everything from STDIN based on my experiments with `mail`.  It seems that it is actually reading the mail to be sent from a queue?  I get a command line like `/usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail -L sm-msp-queue -Ac -qp15s -odd`.  Not sure if there is some way I can intercept the message from the queue and then pass it to sendmail.  I will look into a procmail filter next.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MikeB's suggestion above.  I thought 'milter' was a typo, but sendmail mail filters literally are called 'milters'.  Go figure.
Anyway, i wrote a milter that lets me modify the outgoing message and i must say it was not nearly as dificult as some of the other things I tried.